# How to use trigger event in a button inside a datagrid in silverlight using relaycommand mvvm

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid

How to use trigger event in a button inside a datagrid in silverlight using relaycommand mvvm

Iam unable to get selected values in to some Dto , it means once i selected a row for delete , the selected item property showing NULL .how to solve it pls

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger event like below in datagrid:

```
 <Button Content="Message"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="234,116,0,0" Name="btnMsg" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" >

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">                    
                <si:CallDataMethod Method="HandleShowMessage"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

You have to add necessary reference for this.

For selecteditem you have to set selected item into datagrid and other thing you have to decalre a property in viewmodel:

In Xaml:

```
 <sdk:DataGrid  Height="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Emp}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEMp,Mode=TwoWay}"  BorderThickness="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto">
```

and in Viewmodel:

```
  private EmpInfo _selectedEMp;
    public EmpInfo SelectedEMp
    {
        get { return _selectedEMp; }
        set
        {
            _selectedEMp = value;
            on("SelectedEMp");
        }
    }
```

Thanks